# How to using MediaPlayerElement to play rtsp stream in WinUI3 (in C++) in real-time within 200ms?

Tags: c++, winui-3, mediaplayerelement

I am using MediaPlayerElement to play rtsp stream in WinUI3 (in C++). Xaml code is like this:

MediaPlayerElement x:name="player" Source="rtsp://192.187.2.567" AutoPlay="true"

And I use "player().MediaPlayer().RealTimePlayback(TRUE)" in .cpp file when initializing the page.

The video stream delays for 350ms. But I want it to play in real-time and the latency is within 200ms.
How can I further decrease the latency? which parameter can be set and how?
Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have a look at [MediaSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.core.mediasource?view=winrt-22621#methods) Methods, you can preload the associated media using [MediaSource.OpenAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.core.mediasource.openasync?view=winrt-22621).

Comment: Thank you very much, do you have a example code on how to use the "OpenAsync" method? That would be great!